# access to shadow dom properties

Tags: javascript, dom, shadow

so here is my  script code

```
class Pop extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
 connectedCallback() {
 let currDoc = document.currentScript.ownerDocument;
  let template = currDoc.querySelector('#pop-up');
  let tmplNode = document.importNode(template.content, true);

  let shadowRoot = this.createShadowRoot();
  shadowRoot.appendChild(tmplNode);
  shadowRoot.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
 }
}
 window.customElements.define("pop-up", Pop);
```

and here is my template

```
<template id="pop-up">
    <style>
     * {
     padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

.btn {
  //styling
}

.btn:hover {
  //styling
}

#box{
    //styling
    display: none;
}

#box h1{
    //styling
}

 </style>

<div id="box">
    <h1> Your Shopping Cart</h1>
    <text id="content"> </text>

    <button class="btn" onclick="close()"> Close </button>
</div>
</template>
```

and in my index file i have this

```
<button class="btn" onclick="pop()">Show Pop</button>
<pop-up id="pop"> pop-up box</pop-up>

<script>
    function pop(){
        document.getElementById("pop").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

I am trying to do a pop-up box. And when i click on the "Show Pop" button i want to change the display property from style to "block" from "none". But for some reason it doesn't work. Im new to this shadow dom elemets and i can't really figure it out.

Comment: i forgot to say that the template and the script are in one file seperate from the index file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to explain everything in this answer, but the following code will give you an overview of how the solution might look like.

MDN, as usual, has the perfect intro for web components and shadow doms [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components)

```js
 class Pop extends HTMLElement {
      constructor() {

        // Always call super first in constructor
        super();
        let template = document.getElementById('pop-up');
        let templateContent = template.content;

        // Create a shadow root
        const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
          .appendChild(templateContent.cloneNode(true));
         
        // attach close listener
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', this.close.bind(this));
      }
     
      //  close pop-up
      close() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
      }

      //  open pop-up
      open() {
        this.style.display = 'block';
      }
    }
    window.customElements.define("pop-up", Pop);
    
     function pop() {
      // notice we are using the open method here 
      document.getElementById("pop").open();
    }
```

```html
  <template id="pop-up">
    <style>
      :host {
        display: none;
      }

      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }

      .btn {
        //styling
      }

      .btn:hover {
        //styling
      }

      #box {
        //styling
        display: none;
      }

      #box h1 {
        //styling
      }
    </style>

    <div id="box">
      <h1> Your Shopping Cart</h1>
      <!-- Notice we are using slots -->
      <slot> </slot>

      <button class="btn"> Close </button>
    </div>
  </template>
  
   <button class="btn" onclick="pop()">Show Pop</button>
  <pop-up id="pop"> pop-up box </pop-up>
```

Comment: can you explain what is the meaning of :host and where do we actually use it in this example?

Comment: and also this chunk of code  "this.close.bind(this)" in the event listener

Comment: The [:host()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:host()) CSS pseudo-class function selects the shadow host of the shadow DOM.

Comment: `this.close.bind(this)`  method creates a new function that, when called, has its `this` keyword set to the provided value.